# mysql convert float to double

Tags: mysql, double, alter-table

It is necessary to change the type of a table field (with data).
From Float type to Double type.
The code that does this:

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table`
CHANGE COLUMN `my_value` `my_value` 
DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `id`;
```

But I got a problem:
All fractional numbers soured:
Old value -> New value:

```
129.8 -> 129.8000030517578
117.9 -> 117.9000015258789
99.2 -> 99.19999694824219
```

How to change the field type without data corruption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. The FLOAT and DOUBLE types represent **approximate** numeric data values. They are stored in such a way that they can contain a wide range of numbers (from very big to very small), but at the cost of being a bit inaccurate.
See [Floating point types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/floating-point-types.html) for more information.

If you require this accuracy, switch to [Fixed point types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fixed-point-types.html) like DECIMAL instead.

Comment: Incorrect; you absolutely can.  The answer below does exactly what the OP asked for.  And here are a few variations on that theme:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70319376/mysql-convert-string-and-float-to-double-round-off-problems

Answer (score 7):

To achieve this, I have done so:

1 variant:
First converted into VARCHAR(255):

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table`
CHANGE COLUMN `my_value` `my_value` 
VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `id`;
```

Second converted into DOUBLE:

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table`
CHANGE COLUMN `my_value` `my_value` 
DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `id`;
```

2 variant:
First converted into DOUBLE(10,2):

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table`
CHANGE COLUMN `my_value` `my_value` 
DOUBLE(10,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `id`;
```

Second converted into DOUBLE:

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table`
CHANGE COLUMN `my_value` `my_value` 
DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `id`;
```

Will it have any problems?

Comment: Does this should work for FLOAT to DECIMAL?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table`
CHANGE COLUMN `my_value` `my_value` 
DOUBLE(10,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `id`;
```

Comment: Good idea, but I can not limit the decimal part

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
ALTER TABLE `table`
CHANGE COLUMN `my_value` `my_value`
decimal(10,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `id`;
```

Comment: but I can not limit the decimal part