# MySql Convert() string and float to double (round off problems)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I recently added a new instance of Maria DB.  It in some cases the new database server gives different results from older versions of Maria DB.  Is there a way to fix the new server to make it work like the old ones?  Maybe a setting in the database config file.

(I'd feel a lot better making my new database work exactly like my old one, rather than changing some working legacy code.)

Barring that, can someone explain what's changed in the database?

The problem comes up when I convert a number to a string and back.  This code has worked for years.
It shows number with the right precision.  But the new Maria DB gets confused and sometimes rounds off too much, and other times it has a lot of unnecessary 0's.

New server (bad):

```
MariaDB [mydb]> select @price := 25.17;
+-----------------+
| @price := 25.17 |
+-----------------+
|           25.17 |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [mydb]> select @price,CONVERT(@price,CHAR),0+CONVERT(@price,CHAR), 0.0+CONVERT(@price,CHAR),0.00000+CONVERT(@price,CHAR),0+CONVERT(CONVERT(@price,CHAR),DECIMAL),0+CONCAT(CONVERT(@price,CHAR)),0+CONCAT(@price),0+CONCAT(@price,""),"25.17"+0 \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                                 @price: 25.17
                   CONVERT(@price,CHAR): 25.17
                 0+CONVERT(@price,CHAR): 25
               0.0+CONVERT(@price,CHAR): 25.2
           0.00000+CONVERT(@price,CHAR): 25.17000
0+CONVERT(CONVERT(@price,CHAR),DECIMAL): 25
         0+CONCAT(CONVERT(@price,CHAR)): 25.17
                       0+CONCAT(@price): 25.17
                    0+CONCAT(@price,""): 25.17
                              "25.17"+0: 25.17
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [mydb]> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------------+
| VERSION()       |
+-----------------+
| 10.5.11-MariaDB |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Old server (good):

```
mysql> select @price := 25.17;
+-----------------+
| @price := 25.17 |
+-----------------+
|           25.17 |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @price,CONVERT(@price,CHAR),0+CONVERT(@price,CHAR), 0.0+CONVERT(@price,CHAR),0.00000+CONVERT(@price,CHAR),0+CONVERT(CONVERT(@price,CHAR),DECIMAL),0+CONCAT(CONVERT(@price,CHAR)),0+CONCAT(@price),0+CONCAT(@price,""),"25.17"+0 \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                                 @price: 25.17
                   CONVERT(@price,CHAR): 25.17
                 0+CONVERT(@price,CHAR): 25.17
               0.0+CONVERT(@price,CHAR): 25.17
           0.00000+CONVERT(@price,CHAR): 25.17
0+CONVERT(CONVERT(@price,CHAR),DECIMAL): 25
         0+CONCAT(CONVERT(@price,CHAR)): 25.17
                       0+CONCAT(@price): 25.17
                    0+CONCAT(@price,""): 25.17
                              "25.17"+0: 25.17
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+--------------------+
| VERSION()          |
+--------------------+
| 5.5.35-MariaDB-log |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

From this example you can see:

- Almost everything on the old server showed me exactly the right number of digits.
- Explicitly converting to decimal does not work on either server.  That function requires you to explicitly set the number of digits after the decimal (defaulting to 0).  I want just the opposite.  I want the database to choose the right number of digits.
- The new server sometimes rounds off too many digits!
- The new server can convert a number to a string correctly.
- The new server can convert a literal string to a number correctly.
- And the new server can convert the result of `concat()` to a number correctly.
- But the new server **gets confused** when it tried to call `convert()` then do a second conversion on the result of the first.

---

If you're curious, I use the two conversions in a row to avoid some problems with roundoff error.  The numbers *always looked right on the screen*, but often **failed when I tried to do math**.  So I told the database to *use exactly the number it was showing me*, not some **internal representation**.

```
mysql> select price,price+0,price="25.17",concat(price)="25.17" from alerts where id = 30631675048;
+-------+--------------------+---------------+-----------------------+
| price | price+0            | price="25.17" | concat(price)="25.17" |
+-------+--------------------+---------------+-----------------------+
| 25.17 | 25.170000076293945 |             0 |                     1 |
+-------+--------------------+---------------+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: i think it is could that mysql gets the precision, from the numbers it adds so and the solution is simple don't add  0.00000 if you don't need that precision

Comment: Yeah, it's looking at the numeric constant, but it's ignoring the interesting value.  It should use both.  It used to use both.

Comment: I'm adding 0 in this example, but that's just a sample.  The real code included lots of numbers.  Some came from the user, some are predefined constants in my code, some come from the database.